# \write and \\ command

Tags: external-files, auxiliary-files

Why I get some errors with the code below, and how can I fix that behaviour?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\newwrite\indexist
\immediate\openout\indexist=classic.ist
\immediate\write\indexist{\\}
\immediate\write\indexist{\catcode`\{=11{\catcode`\{=2 text}
\immediate\write\indexist{other text\catcode`\}=11}\catcode`\}=2}
\immediate\closeout\indexist
\end{document}
```

Comment: ``\string\\`` (you're forgetting that `\write` does complete expansion). Why would you write on a `.ist` file? Isn't it easier writing it with an editor?

Comment: @egreg I have updated my question... I would to write on a .ist file because I want to automatize the procedure to get the index formatted correctly from the .ist file...

Comment: There's no point in writing an `.ist` file one line at a time with `\write`; the `filecontents*` environment may be much better for the task at hand.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem with `\\` is already solved by egreg: `\string\\`. That prevents expansion and converts `\\` to two `\` tokens with catcode 12 (same catcode as digits).

The same is needed for unmatched `{` and `}`. However unmatched braces do not work
inside `\write`. A trick is using macros that are defined via `\edef` (expanded def),
then `\leftbracechar` and `\rightbracechar` contain the braces as tokens with catcode 12.

```
\documentclass{article}

\edef\leftbracechar{\string{}
\edef\rightbracechar{\string}}

\begin{document}
\newwrite\indexist
\immediate\openout\indexist=classic.ist
\immediate\write\indexist{\string\\}
\immediate\write\indexist{\leftbracechar text}
\immediate\write\indexist{other text\rightbracechar}
\immediate\closeout\indexist
\end{document}
```